# jquery onclick load div

Tags: jquery, html, click, onload

May I know is it possible to do this in jquery?

I have a category link:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Moulds</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the content are seperated by div

```
<div id="tools">This is the tools content</div>
<div id="moulds">This is the moulds content</div>
<div id="videos">This is the videos content</div>
```

by default it will show tools content and other twos (moulds and videos) div are hidden. They only show when the menu is click. On top of that is it possible to put loading picture when loading the other div or something like fade in fade out animation?

Can this be done? i search over stackoverflow but none of them meet what i want..

thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, of course it can be done. Which part are you having problems with?

Comment: you can put an inimation like this too http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/css3-loading-spinners-without-images/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a tab / something similar. Anyways, you can do this way, but before, change the HTML this way:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tools">Tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="#moulds">Moulds</a></li>
    <li><a href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in the JavaScript give this way:

```
$("ul li a").click(function(){
    theDiv = $(this).attr("href");
    $(theDiv).show();
});
```

If you want only one `div` to be shown, you can do this way:

```
$("ul li a").click(function(){
    $("div").hide();
    theDiv = $(this).attr("href");
    $(theDiv).show();
});
```

My suggestion would be, using a common class for both the `<div>`s and `<a>`s.

---

Finally, you might arrive to this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="link" href="#tools">Tools</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#moulds">Moulds</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab" id="tools">This is the tools content</div>
<div class="tab" id="moulds">This is the moulds content</div>
<div class="tab" id="videos">This is the videos content</div>
```

And then, the event handling would be:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
    $(".tab").hide();
    theDiv = $(this).attr("href");
    $(theDiv).show();
});
```

Comment: yup this is exactly what i want but default it show all 3 div, i only want tools div to show by default and other two are hidden until the link is click then it only show. on top of that can add fadein fadeout animation when click to load?

Comment: nope.. i totally didnt learn before jquery thats why im asking this question :) animation may not be important but the most important is i only want tools div to load on default and not all 3 div... [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UgaSv/)

Comment: Okay, give this: `$(document).ready(function(){ $(".tab").hide(); $("#tools").show(); });`

Comment: now may i know where should i include the fadein and fadeout function?

Comment: In the Script section, before everything.

Answer (score 0):

hy

fadings are quite easy in jquery. here a sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>js test</h1>

<ul id="myMenu">
    <li><a href="#" data-id="tools">Tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="modules">Moulds</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="videos">Videos</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="subcontent" id="tools" style="display:block">tools</div>
<div class="subcontent" id="modules">modules</div>
<div class="subcontent" id="videos">videos</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#myMenu').on('click','a',function()
    {
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.subcontent:visible').fadeOut();
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.subcontent[id='+$(this).attr('data-id')+']').fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    div.subcontent { display:none; }
</style>
```

we register a event handler with $('#myMenu').on(..) witch listens on clicks on a link element (a) and fades out first all open (visible) divs. then it starts with fading in. in this case the fade out and fade in methods starts at the same time. with a callback function you're able to call this 2 steps after each other.